# Should we implement the accesskey HTML attribute?

Tags: html, accessibility, usability

I'm researching whether to add [accesskeys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) to our site and was wondering if they are commonly used nowadays for accessibility. I checked out the source code on a dozen or so large websites and didn't see them used in any of the sites. Is it considered best practice to implement them for navigation, search, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard access is on the way down. My suggestion would be. If your site is like a forum or a game, where a user may constantly repeat the same actions, then you could help them by providing an access key.

Otherwise only a few buttons such as Search would benefit from it.  Here are some concerns from [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey)

> **Accessibility concerns**
> In addition to poor browser support, there are numerous concerns with the accesskey attribute:
>
> - An accesskey value can conflict with a system or browser keyboard shortcut, or assistive technology functionality. What may work for one combination of operating system, assistive technology, and browser may not work with other combinations.
> - Certain accesskey values may not be present on certain keyboards, especially when internationalization is a concern. So adapting to specific languages could cause further problems.
> - accesskey values that rely on numbers may be confusing to individuals experiencing cognitive concerns, where the number doesn't have a logical association with the functionality it triggers.
> - Informing the user that accesskeys are present, so that they are aware of the functionality. If the system lacks a method of notifying the user about this feature, the user might accidentally activate accesskeys.
>
> Because of these issues, it is generally advised not to use accesskeys for most general-purpose websites and web apps.

Comment: I get so frustrated when I'm editing a post here on Stack Exchange and ctrl-G doesn't "find aGain" like it is supposed to and instead triggers image upload. A real world example of the conflicts that can happen and be bad for user experience.